# Horizontal slowness in seismology

Tags: seismology, waves

I am working on a seismology assignment and it starts with the fundamentals of seismology such as the wave equation, the slowness... such as the question below:

*write an equation describing the horizontal slowness (reciprocal of the velocity). This becomes a vector quantity for propagation in multiple directions.*

I haven't fully grasped these concepts yet. And I looked around for lecture notes and this is what I found:
[MIT-introduction to seismology](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/earth-atmospheric-and-planetary-sciences/12-510-introduction-to-seismology-spring-2010/lecture-notes/lec5.pdf) and [image: continuum mechanics lecture notes]

I am not sure which one is the answer to this question or what is even the difference between the two because they both seem to represent the slowness

Comment: Whoah, that seems like a lot of research! (So many tabs.)

Comment: Well... I have to x(